# Does any of search engine provide its search data publicly?

Tags: search, google-search-api

I need the data of daily searches that people do on most search engines.

Comment: Yes, this is off-topic here. From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to find. Perhaps Google Trends is an option?

[Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/)

Comment: Actually, it has a limited number of searches. I need the whole data that people search on search engine. Thanks for your answer